# Best way to structure classes for accounts (Active Directory, Gmail, etc.) in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm starting to develop a set of classes to house account information.  I need to perform CRUD operations on a number of different types of accounts (Active Directory, Google Apps, and others).  I am trying to design the classes properly to start with so that they conform to OO principles and they are flexible for the future.

To give you a bit of background, I am maintaining and updating user accounts in our proximity card system, our Active Directory, our Google Apps account, and possibly a few others in the future.  Each system has a different way of doing things but they do have similarities.  I want to create an interface that I can code against in a way that I can drop in new account classes down the road without major changes.

The problem is that I think I might need two classes for each type of account.  One class should hold the user information (for example, first name, last name, etc.)  However, I need a way to find a user in each system.  At first I thought of putting the FindUser method inside the class.  That would work if we were only returning one user.  However, I may ask for all the users with a first name of "Tom".  That might return five users.  I wouldn't want one class spawning four more instances of itself because I wouldn't know where to store them.  My thought, then, would be to have a class with the methods that stores one or more instances of a class that contains just the data.

For instance, in Active Directory, I would have the following basic structure:

```
MainClass:
FindUser()
FindUsers()
List<ADUsers>

ADUsers:
_firstName
_lastName
_userName
_etc.
```

Thus, the MainClass would be used to perform the FindUser/s methods and the users could be accessed through the list.

The other option would be to have the MainClass FindUser method return an instance of the ADUsers class and the FindUsers method return a List of ADUsers.

My question is, is this the right way to approach this overall problem?  Don't forget that I have to expand this to handle all different types of user systems.  The above example would end up being my basic interface that I would extend for more complex cases.

Writing the actual code itself is not my issue (it is almost all done).  My issue is laying it out properly in an intelligent design.  Your help there would be much appreciated.  As for language specifications, I am writing this in C#.

Comment: Q1. Are you ever going to aggregate different accounts for the same user, i.e. "User's AD UPN is john@mycompany.local, AD display name=John Peterson, and he also owns the facebook ID=123FF0000000012354 display name=GayJohnny91" ? Q2. What operations are possible on users? Just search? Do you need to store them in RDBMS? Send over the wire? Q3. When you search, do you know what data store are you going to use for searching, or you need the function "gimme all users where first name is tom, from all identity providers including AD and Google"?

Comment: @Soonts - A1.  We will do very little account aggregation.  Basically, we may create multiple accounts (AD, Google Apps, etc.) at the same time for one user.  We may also delete all accounts for a user, etc.  We won't be looking to have them tied together in groups (we won't get a list of users with all of their accounts attached).

Comment: @Soonts - A2.  There will be a number of operations performed on an account.  For example, we will have the following (and more) methods: UnlockAccount(), ExpireAccount(), SetExtendedProperties(), ActivateAccount(), ListGroupAssociations(), etc.  As for storage and transmission, we won't be storing these objects.  We will be creating them just to perform actions on them.  We don't need persistance.  As for transmission, possibly.  We may use this with WCF.

Comment: @Soonts - A3.  The search will know which data store to look in.  We will most likely find a primary account (probably AD account) and then use the UniqueID from there (we use the employeeID field in AD for this) to find other accounts.  We will, at times, also reverse that so that we find a Google Apps user and use that info to find an AD account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't put a find method in each type of user, objects should be unaware of their persistence. Instead why not treat things as a repository? You'd have something like

```
IUserRepository<T>
  public T Create()
  public T Load(object identifer);
  public void Save(T user);
```

etc. And then have an interface for a base user;

```
IUser
  public object Identifier { get }
  public string Email { get }
```

etc. and implement concrete versions for an AD User, a Google Apps user etc, and matching repositories. You could use the factory pattern to return the right type of repository according to your configuration or whatever else you like?

Comment: I'm thinking that is the way I'm going to go.  So the implementation of the repository should be where I store the list of users, which are implementations of IUser?

Comment: Well, you'd store them in whatever the backing store is - the implementation would write to AD, or the GoogleApps user system and so on, and load as necessary. Whether you cache or not within the repository is up to you, based on if you think the store may change underneath you.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:** I'm familiar with LDAP and ADSI. Just read some specs about Google Contacts Data API. I only worked with cards on the very low level, using e.g. PKCS#11 API, so most likely I know nothing about the cards API you're using.

My opinion on the topic is: there's too much difference to try to hide that difference behind an abstraction layer. They have different query languages. Even the e-mail is stored differently: in AD you have the single "mail" sttribute, in google contacts you've got the array of structures, with 1 mandatory and 4 optional fields in each of them. Google API is stateless HTTP request/response, ADSI/LDAP is statefull session-based.

Maybe if I had more information about what your smart card API, and the functional requirements for the system you're designing, I'd come up with something more clever.

Comment: I'm not trying to use one method do do searches on all of my different systems.  I'm looking to create a common interface for the common methods and properties that I will need.  For example, all systems will have a unique identifier for the user, they will all ask for first name and last name, and they will all have some sort of authentication (password, smartID, etc.) to be set.  Thanks for the suggestions.